# SED - display lines with 3 'x' signs

Tags: sed, regular-expression

i have a problem with a task from title.
By using SED i have to display lines with 3 'x' signs.

I know how to do it with one sign, but i can't write working command for 3 signs.

Example input:

```
   blaxblax 
   xxox
   xxx23
   0x1a
   xxxx
```

output:

```
   xxox
   xxx23
```

Comment: How does this relate this to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414312/grep-find-lines-with-3-the-same-signsdont-have-to-be-in-a-row? Can you think of ways to apply the solution proposed there to the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do here is create a regular expression that matches:

- starting from the beginning of the line, (zero or more non-"x" characters followed by an "x") 3 times
- followed by zero or more non-"x" characters until the end of the line

With sed you'd write (assuming GNU sed)

```
sed -rn '/^([^x]*x){3}[^x]*$/p'
```

Answer (score 4):

Short GNU **`awk`** approach:

```
awk -v FPAT='x' 'NF==3' file
```

- `FPAT` - pattern defining field value
- `NF` - total number of fields (in our case - the number of `x` char occurrences)

---

The output:

```
xxox
xxx23
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/x\{2,3\}/p' test.txt |sed '/x\{4,\}/d'
```

Output:

```
xxox
xxx23
```

Answer (score 0):

Another GNU `sed` approach

```
sed -n 's/x/x/3;T;s/x/x/4;t;p'
```

POSIXly, you'd use `grep`, no need for `sed` for that:

```
grep -Ex '([^x]*x){3}[^x]*'
```

`grep pattern` can always be written `sed '/pattern/!d'` though POSIX sed only understands BREs so:

```
sed '/^\([^x]*x\)\{3\}[^x]*$/!d'
```

With `awk`:

```
awk -F x 'NF == 4'
```